# Is the following set dense?

Tags: normed-spaces

Which of the following sets are dense in $C[0,1]$ with respect to sup-norm topology?

1. $\left\{f\in C[0,1] : \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=5\right\}$
2. $\left\{f\in C[0,1] :\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx =0 \right\}$

My attempts: for option 2) ... I know that $\{f\in C[0,1] :\int_{0}^{1}f(x)d\,\mathrm x=0\}$ is nowhere dense if I take $f(0) =0$.
Im consfused about option 1... I have no any idea about it. Please help and tell me the solution I would be more thankful.

Answer (score 1):

One knows that convergence in sup-norm means uniform convergence, and it's well known that if $f_n\to f$ uniformly then $\int f_n \to \int f$.

Therefore, neither $\{f\in C[0,1] : \int_0^1 f(x)\, {\rm d}x = 5\}$ nor $\{f\in C[0,1] : \int_0^1 f(x)\, {\rm d}x = 0\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$. Can you see it?

Comment: @ rldias not getting,,,$int_{0}^{1} f(x) = 5 $  it converge to  5  ..can u elaborate more ?

Comment: Sequences in such sets will only (uniformly) converge to functions $g\in C[0,1]$ with $\int_0^1 g(x)\, {\rm d}x \in \{0,5\}$.

Comment: @lomberlego In other words, these sets are closed. Their closure cannot be $C[0,1]$.